# How to display (mask) a certain character as another

Tags: faces

I want to display every `&` character in my code as a `λ` instead. But I don't want the file to be changed. It must be just a "visual effect".

- `&` *Ampersand U+0026 Unicode*
- `λ` *Greek Small Letter Lamda U+03BB Unicode*

Like:

`Enum.reduce([1, 2, 3], &+/2)`

To be shown as:

`Enum.reduce([1, 2, 3], λ+/2)`

Is that possible? How?

Answer (score 1):

The built-in `prettify-symbol-mode` can do this simply by adding `("&" . "λ")` to `prettify-symbol-alist` and turning on the mode:

```
(add-to-list 'prettify-symbols-alist '("&" . "λ"))
(global-prettify-symbols-mode)
```

This can be added to the mode hook if you only want this for a single mode.

Comment: I have wrote it in my `init.el` file, even after reload `&` characters still being shown as `&`. What else I need to do?

Comment: (But 'lambda' words are being shown as `λ`)

Comment: `prettify-symbols-alist` is a mode local so you may need to set this in the hook for the mode you want this in.

Answer (score 0):

Adapted from `pretty-lambda-mode` in [**`pretty-lambdada.el`**](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/pretty-lambdada.el) (see [Pretty Lambda](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/PrettyLambda)):

```el
(defun pretty-ampersand (&optional mode)
  "Display `&' as the Greek letter `λ'.
Non-nil optional arg means use pretty-ampersand display in that MODE.
nil means use pretty-ampersand display for the current mode."
  (font-lock-add-keywords
   mode `(("&"
           (0 (progn (compose-region (match-beginning 0) (match-end 0)
                                     ,(make-char 'greek-iso8859-7 107))
                     nil))))))

(define-minor-mode pretty-ampersand-mode
    "Buffer-local minor mode to display `&' as the Greek letter `λ`.
With ARG, turn mode on if ARG is positive, off otherwise."
  :init-value nil
  (cond (pretty-ampersand-mode
         (pretty-ampersand)
         (font-lock-fontify-buffer))
        (t
         (font-lock-remove-keywords
          nil `(("&"
                 (0 (progn (compose-region (match-beginning 0) (match-end 0)
                                           ,(make-char 'greek-iso8859-7 107))
                           nil)))))
         (save-excursion
           (goto-char (point-min))
           (while (re-search-forward "&" nil t)
             (decompose-region (match-beginning 0) (match-end 0)))))))
```

If you want `&` to be shown as `λ` only in some syntactic contexts, e.g., only when surrounded by whitespace, then adjust the regexp `"&"` accordingly.

If you want to use this in all buffers/modes, then try this:

```el
(define-globalized-minor-mode global-pretty-ampersand-mode
    pretty-ampersand-mode turn-on-pretty-ampersand-mode
    "Global minor mode to display `&' as the Greek letter `λ'.
With ARG, turn mode on if ARG is positive, off otherwise.")

(defun turn-on-pretty-ampersand-mode  () (pretty-ampersand-mode  1))
(defun turn-off-pretty-ampersand-mode () (pretty-ampersand-mode -1))
```

Comment: I have added it to my `init.el` file, also added the following line at the end: `(pretty-ampersand-mode t)`. My intention is to auto-start this mode when emacs starts. But it didn't worked. The effect only take place when I explicitly reload the `init.el` file with `M-x load-file`. How can I set it to be auto-started? Thank you.

Comment: It's because a minor mode is buffer-local, by default. I've added a globalized version, `global-pretty-ampersand-mode`, which will turn it on by default in all modes.

Comment: Added your third function definition to my file but nothing happened. And when I call `(global-pretty-ampersand-mode t)` it errors: `Symbol's function definition is void: turn-on-pretty-ampersand-mode`.

Comment: Forgot to add its definition. Really, all I'm doing here is taking stuff from [`pretty-lambdada.el`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/pretty-lambdada.el) and changing the function names (and changing the regexp from `"\\<lambda\\>"` to `"&"`). There is a bit more in that file, but I've copied nearly all of it here now. You *could* just look there and write what you need...